Insert big json file into a mongo collection using mongosh
I need to insert a 181 KB json file into a mongo collection, the restriction is that it needs to be done using mongosh.
json_file_path=/some/path/file.json
json_file_string=$(cat $json_file_path)

/mongo/path/monhosh $databaseName \
    --tlsCertificateKeyFile someAuthDetails \
    --tlsCAFile someMoreAuthDetails
    --quiet \
    --eval "db.test_collection.insertOne(${json_file_string})" 

this seems to be working for smaller files, but with 181 KB, which is not that big, it fails as follows:
-ksh: /mongo/path/monhosh: cannot execute [Arguments list too long]

ive increased ulimit -s from 8000 to 65000, which seems to be the maximum with no luck. any ideas ?

Apart from the given answer: why are you restricted to mongosh?

You have correctly identified the issue: the size of the data exceeds what can be passed in as arguments/params/data to any script or program. What you're doing is loading the whole file's data into a shell variable and expanding that in eval.
Instead, that can be built as a script, since you are restricted to only using shell commands & mongosh. And that script .js file will be passed to mongosh using the --file param. Since the file will be read directly and doesn't need the contents to be passed as a param, the file can get as big as it needs to be.
Example contents of my_file.json with cat my_file.json:
{
    "_id": 123,
    "first": "Name",
    "last": "something"
}

1. Select the DB you want to use:
echo 'db = db.getSiblingDB("stacko");' > temp.js


note the use of > so that it creates a new temp.js file
replace 'stacko' with whichever DB you want to use.
since you have the DB in a variable, use that var with double-quotes and use single-inner-quotes for the:

echo "db = db.getSiblingDB('$databaseName');" > temp.js

2. Add an insertOne statement:
echo 'db.test_collection.insertOne(' >> temp.js


note the use of double >> so that it appends to the temp.js file
replace "test_collection" with your collection name

3. Put the contents of your json file into temp.js:
cat my_file.json >> temp.js

4. Add the closing parens and semicolon after that:
echo ');' >> temp.js

5. [Optional] Check the file with cat temp.js:
db = db.getSiblingDB('stacko');
db.test_collection.insertOne(
{
    "_id": 123,
    "first": "Name",
    "last": "something"
}
);

6. Execute temp.js it with the --file option to mongosh:
mongosh <connection options as above> --file=temp.js

In your case, that would be:
/mongo/path/monhosh $databaseName \
 --tlsCertificateKeyFile someAuthDetails \
 --tlsCAFile someMoreAuthDetails
 --file temp.js

If you want to insert many existing documents from .json files like this, then repeat steps 2, 3, 4 before finally doing step 6. Or create separate .js scripts to execute with mongosh --file some_file.js.

thanks @aneroid, it worked as a charm !
